# gl.glScalef() hide the gl.glDrawArrays() drawing

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have a program which draw a 3D shape according to set of `GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` , finally it drawn within the  `display()` method  -

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
}
```

so far it work ok and I get the desired shape on the output  , but if I add `gl.glScalef(20, 20, 40);` before the `gl.glDrawArrays()` the shape stop to be appear and I get blank output  -

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    gl.glScalef(20, 20, 40);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
}
```

How could I scale the output correctly ?

**Edit:**

Fixed by adding `gl.glLoadIdentity()` before  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally unclear what the rest of your code will do, but from the shown fragments alone, one could suspect that you never reset the matrix, and the scaling accumulates over the course of several frames.

Comment: It turn out you right  , I just added `gl.glLoadIdentity()` before the scaling and it worked out !